# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

When I run the app I am getting following error

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

here is my mainactivity.java class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView rvContacts = findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
        contacts = Contact.createContactsList(20);
        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter();items
        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast `RecyclerView` like this..

```
RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
```

and also you need to call `setContentView(R.id.your_layout)` to set your layout.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `setContentView()` in your onCreate of `MainActivity`

so add line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` check code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //change here

        RecyclerView rvContacts = findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);

        // Initialize contacts
        contacts = Contact.createContactsList(20);
        // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter();
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        // That's all!
    }
}
```